# User Adonisjs Auth falhando error responseText: 'E_INVALID_AUTH_UID: User not found', guard: 'api'

Tags: javascript, typescript, adonisjs

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto de login, usando postman para rotas, travei na parte em que preciso gerar um token usando Adonisjs (lucid) vinculado ao MySQL.
Me apresente seguinte error : responseText:
'E_INVALID_AUTH_UID: User not found',
guard: 'api'

**MODELS**

```
User.ts
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import { column, beforeSave, BaseModel } from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm'
import Hash from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Hash'


export default class User extends BaseModel {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  public id: number

  @column()
  public email: string

  @column({ serializeAs: null })
  public password: string

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  public createdAt: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  public updatedAt: DateTime

  @beforeSave()
  public static async hashPassword (user: User) {
    if (user.$dirty.password) {
      user.password = await Hash.make(user.password)}
}}
```

**Routes**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is dedicated for defining HTTP routes. A single file is enough
| for majority of projects, however you can define routes in different
| files and just make sure to import them inside this file. For example
|
| Define routes in following two files
| ├── start/routes/cart.ts
| ├── start/routes/customer.ts
|
| and then import them inside `start/routes.ts` as follows
|
| import './routes/cart'
| import './routes/customer'
|
*/

import Route from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route'



Route.get('/', async () => {})

Route.post('login', async ({ auth, request, response }) => {
    const email = request.input('email')
    const password = request.input('password')
  

  
    try {

      const token = await auth.use('api').attempt(email, password)
      
      return token
    } 
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      
      return response.unauthorized("invalid credentials")
    } 
  })


Route.get('dashboard', async ({ auth }) => {


  await auth.use('api').authenticate()
 
  auth.use('api').isLoggedIn 

  return `Você esta logado! !`
})
  

Route.resource('/users', 'UsersController') // atalho do adonis que uso para montar todas as rotas com 1 linha de code.
```

**ERROR impresso no terminal**

```
    InvalidCredentialsException: E_INVALID_AUTH_UID: User not found
    at Function.invalidUid (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\node_modules\@adonisjs\auth\build\src\Exceptions\InvalidCredentialsException.js:25:23)
    at OATGuard.verifyCredentials (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\node_modules\@adonisjs\auth\build\src\Guards\Base\index.js:131:77)
    at OATGuard.attempt (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\node_modules\@adonisjs\auth\build\src\Guards\Oat\index.js:204:33)
    at Object.handler (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\start\routes.ts:35:43)
    at Object.PreCompiler.runRouteHandler [as fn] (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\node_modules\@adonisjs\http-server\build\src\Server\PreCompiler\index.js:44:50)
    at Runnable.invoke (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\node_modules\co-compose\build\src\Runnable.js:55:48)
    at BodyParserMiddleware.handle (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\node_modules\@adonisjs\bodyparser\build\src\BodyParser\index.js:161:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Server.handleRequest (C:\Users\João\Desktop\be\api\node_modules\@adonisjs\http-server\build\src\Server\index.js:108:13) {
  responseText: 'E_INVALID_AUTH_UID: User not found',
  guard: 'api'
```

O notei tambem que minha pasta "node_modules" e "build" estao meio apagadas na lateral, olhem:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgl9q.png)

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, se tiver alguma consideração ou detalhe que precisa adicionar a uma de suas perguntas você pode clicar em Editar. Siga as [orientações ja passadas](/questions/589180/estou-tentando-fazer-auth-de-token-via-adonijs-de-um-usuario-usando-postman-par#comment1025502_589180) para melhorar a pergunta original. Os comentários aqui foram bloqueados, qualquer necessidade de comentar pode ser feita na pergunta original.